# Eclispe does not show progress bar of user threads

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, progress, jobs

I created some user jobs on start-up of eclipse, but after launching the workbench I am not able to see the progress bar. Is there anywhere I have to mention these threads other than making them user threads?

```java
protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    monitor.beginTask("Download", -1);
    for (ProxyBean network : ProxyBean.get()) {
        // do something
    }
    monitor.done();
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
}
```

I initialize it in this way:

```java
job = new MyJob();
job.setUser(true);
job.schedule();`
```

Comment: You might be starting the jobs before the `ProgressProvider` has been registered with the job manager. You may also need to call `monitor.worked()`.

Comment: @greg-449, this is the right answer - when you are using `monitor.beginTask` you should also call `monitor.worked()`

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are applying it on correct shell, or the execution time of job is too low so that you can not see the progress bar..

You can also use:

```
// Update the user interface asynchronously
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // ... do any work that updates the screen ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I am using it and threads execution time is not too low as I can see the sysouts coming