# Eclipse job with UI access

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jobs

I have one situation.
I have one Eclipse job with following code:

```java
private class ExecutionJob extends Job {
    public static final String MY_FAMILY = "myJobFamily";

    public ExecutionJob(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("executing ...... ", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
        methodForExecution();
        monitor.done();
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
        return family == MY_FAMILY;
    }
}
```

And this methodForExecution() has code as below :

```java
public void methodForExecution(){
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("view_id");
}
```

Now, the situation is, job opens up something like progressmonitor, and my method is trying to access UI which is actually behind this job's progressmonitor. And it gives NullPointerException as the progress monitor does not have ActiveWorkbenchWindow.

I can not use UIJob, as I have to execute this methodForExecution() asynchronously.
Can someone please help me resolving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you want to run **must** run in the UI thead.

If most of the work in the job is updating the UI and there is no long running non-UI code then you should use `UIJob` to run this. This is still scheduled as a job but the `runInUIThread` method is executed in the UI thread.

If you have a lot of non-UI code especially long running code then use a normal `Job` but you will have to use `Display.asyncExec` to run the method in the UI thread:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      methodForExecution();
    }
  });
```

In Java 8 you could do:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(this::methodForExecution);
```

You can also use `syncExec` instead of `asyncExec` to wait for the UI to update.

If the `showView` is all you want to do you could just do the `asyncExec` without using a `Job`.

Comment: I am facing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325603/eclispe-does-not-show-progress-bar-of-user-threads issue while using UIJob

Comment: If all you are doing is a show view the job is going to finish very quickly and won't have time to show a progress bar

Comment: I have updated the answer to be more explicit about when to use UIJob or a normal Job.

Comment: Yes, so the situation is - 
lots of non-UI long running code and lots of UI code.So, if I use UIJob, the progress monitor does not shows up and if I use worker Job , there might be over flow due to so many runnables.

Comment: You can use `syncExec` instead to `asyncExec` to wait for the UI to update.